# How to get similar performance with hyper-v r2 and native server with sql 2008 server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, performance, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

We currently have a physical server with 4 physical [cpu](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=40200). Which will be the best VM configuration for SQL Server?

If I configure my native server I will have much better performance because I will not be limited by only 4 CPUs. So is there a way to assign physical CPUs with Hyper-V so that the guest gets access to the entire CPU (and all its cores) rather than just the cores being presented as individual CPUs?

Comment: a 4 vcpu limit has not been a limiting factor in our case, its always io or ram or both.

Answer (score 2):

No, the VM is limited to 4 vCPUs under Hyper-V.  Each vCPU is a single core in the physical world.  If you need more than 4 cores for your database server then it isn't a good candidate for virtualization.